# How to tell if returned data from API call is newer than previously pulled data?

Tags: node.js, rest, axios

I'm using an online IoT service ([TagoIO](https://tago.io)) and want to routinely get data from an API to store on the platform. The platform allows you to setup an [Analysis](https://tago.io/analysis) where you create the code to pull from the API & store it, and then you can setup an automation to run it at a given interval.

The API I'm pulling up should update with new data every hour (although I'm unsure as to exactly what minute of each hour new data is available, and therefore, I currently have it automated to pull data every 30mins). There's also the possibility that there may not be new data for a given hour and so if you pull data, then it will return the previous hour's.

I want to ensure that when I pull data from the API, that the data is newer than the previous data I've pulled. My current approach has been to compare the timestamps of the retrieved data to the last pulled data, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient manner to do this. Comparing the timestamps often is cumbersome given the different formatting, and it would be much better if there was a consistent, conventional indicator that I could quickly know whether or not the data is new.

It should be noted that I've been using NodeJS with Axios to pull from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how the API is structured. If it is a **REST API**, chances are the API utilizes the [etag/if-none-match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) method to determine if the data has changed since your last call.

Well designed REST APIs send you an **etag header** inside the response that you store with your last dataset on your side. on the next server query call for this resource, you send this stored etag hash inside the **if-none-match** header. The server now uses this information to determine, if he has more recent data that he needs to send you, or if you already have the latest information available. if no new data is availalbe the server responds with a 304 status code. if there is new data, you just get the 200 with your new data.

I would hit TagoIO support and ask if this behaviour is available. If not, checking the last called timestamp seems like the only way left.

The TagoIO API states, that the datasets look somewhat like this:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "6143842f561c4e00199f517b",
      "device": "612ea1694035dd0012f6d238",
      "variable": "temperature",
      "value": -11.67,
      "unit": "°C",
      "group": "1631814703672",
      "time": "2021-09-16T17:51:43.672Z",
      "created_at": "2021-09-16T17:51:43.672Z",
      "location": {
        "type": "point",
        "coordinates": [
          -78.677328,
          35.770723
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The time and/or created_at properties seems viable to use for a [JS datetime comparison](https://upstackhq.com/blog/software-development/how-to-compare-datetime-in-javascript). Maybe, there is a part inside the ID as well that hints to creation time and can be used for easy comparisons.

Hope that helps,
Mike